# I'm having trouble creating a drop-down sort menu for an e-commerce website

Tags: django

Let me start of by saying I'm new to Django and programming in general. Spent time learning python and started with django a little over a month ago. I can trying to create a browse tap on an e-commerce app that has a drop down menu where you can select a category and it will sort. I think the work I need to do is in views, but am unsure of the code to write.

```
Views: 
    def browse(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
           form = CategoryChoicesForm(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

model:
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Accessories', 'Accessories'),
    ('Bags', 'Bags'),
    ('Basic Tees', 'Basic Tees'),
    ('Belts', 'Belts'),
    ('Blazers', 'Blazers'),
    ('Boots', 'Boots'),
    ('Button Downs', 'Button Downs'),
    ('Cardigans', 'Cardigans'),
    ('Denim', 'Denim'),
    ('Footwear', 'Footwear'),
    ('Gloves', 'Gloves'),
    ('Hats', 'Hats'),
    ('Headphones', 'Headphones'),
    ('Henleys', 'Henleys'),
    ('Home', 'Home'),
    ('Jackets', 'Jackets'),
    ('Jewelry', 'Jewelry'),
    ('Outerwear', 'Outerwear'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    ('Pants', 'Pants'),
    ('Polos', 'Polos'),
    ('Scarves', 'Scarves'),
    ('Shirts', 'Shirts'),
    ('Shoes','Shoes'),
    ('Sneakers', 'Sneakers'),
    ('socks', 'Socks'),
    ('Sunglasses', 'Sunglasses'),
    ('Sweaters', 'Sweaters'),
    ('Sweatshirts', 'Sweatshirts'),
    ('Tank Tops', 'Tank Tops'),
    ('Tech', 'Tech'),
    ('T-Shirts', 'T-Shirts'),
    ('Undergarments', 'Undergarments'),
    ('Wallets', 'Wallets'),
    ('Watches', 'Watches'),
    )
    class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    item_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SIZE_CHOICES, blank=True)
        item_brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand')
        category = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_name

Form:
    class CategoryChoicesForm(forms.Form):
        items = Item.get_category_display
        categoryoption = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=items, empty_label=None)
```

Comment: How do I write the view so that I can select different categories from the drop down menu in my template and it will sort the items in the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class based generic view (ListView). Have a good read of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/). Specifically the sections on [viewing a subset of objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#viewing-subsets-of-objects) and [dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering).

Personally I think you should drop the form all together and add your own `<a>` tags to a [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/). So maybe read up on the [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/) too. I think you need the [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function (possibly in the template).

As a basic outline -

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from books.models import Item

class CategoryListView(ListView):

    template_name = "item_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = name__iexact=self.args[0])
        return Item.objects.filter(publisher=publisher)
```

You need an entry in URLconf to get the `self.args[0]` and you'll need to write a template for `"item_list.html"`